# Adjusting margins of a single page using memoir

Tags: margins, memoir

My Table of Contents is too long, leading to the Appendix entry being pushed to the next page. I would like to keep the entire content on one page. I have already made sure that the table of contents does not have its own entry, and I cannot remove other entries.

I have been able to adjust the margins of the entire document using

```
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.4cm}{4cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

but I do not know how to adjust the margins of a single page.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If your TOC looks like egreg's, you could put it into 2 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example document that shows the behavior:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.4cm}{4cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage*{\baselineskip}}

\chapter{Title}\section{Abc}\section{Def}\section{Ghi}\section{Jkl}\section{Mno}

\chapter{Title}\section{Abc}\section{Def}\section{Ghi}

\chapter{Title}\section{Abc}\section{Def}\section{Ghi}

\chapter{Title}\section{Abc}\section{Def}\section{Ghi}

\chapter{Title}\section{Abc}\section{Def}\section{Ghi}

\chapter{Title}\section{Abc}\section{Def}\section{Ghi}

\chapter{Title}\section{Abc}\section{Def}\section{Ghi}

\chapter{Title}\section{Abc}\section{Def}\section{Ghi}

\appendix

\chapter{Title}

\end{document}
```

If you comment out the `\addtocontents` line, the appendix will go to a page by itself.

[image]

You may need to add more space, so perhaps

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage*{2\baselineskip}}
```

would do. Experiment with your document.

If the enlargement needed is more than one line, you may also want to cover your tracks by removing the page number; in this case add

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
```